# Refactor functions to use currying

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying, partial-application

I have three functions that I would like to refactor using currying but I am struggling get my head around functions that return functions. I am trying to break down and design the curried functions as a starting point.

I found this [medium article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-currying-in-javascript-ceb2188c339) that gives a very simple design.

```js
function discount(discount) {
    return (price) => {
        return price * discount;
    }
}

const tenPercentDiscount = discount(0.1);

tenPercentDiscount(500);
```

At a high level, my functions get called like so:

```js
getCatHelper(prioritisedBreeds, catDefintions, debugToggle)
  .then((breed) => setConfigData(breed, config))
  .catch(() => false);
```

- if: `debugToggle` - it passes it `mapCatValueToKey` to get the cat breed
- else: makes a network request, passes an array of `catBreeds` to `getPriorityBreed`
- sets some data with the returned `breed` and a `config` within scope

```js
getPriorityBreed(prioritisedBreeds, catBreeds, catDefintions)
```

- calls `mapCatValueToKey` to map over the `catBreeds` and make a new array with the `catDefintions`
- loops through two lists - the `prioritisedBreeds` and the `mappedCats` from above to return the priority `breed`

```js
mapCatValueToKey(breed, catDefintions)
```

- mapping function to map a breed (value) to a cat definition object

---

Here's how `getCatHelper` is being called:

```js
function useCatHook(
  config: Config,
  catDefintions: any = CAT_DEFS,
  getCat: (
      prioritisedBreeds,
      catDefintions,
      debugToggle,
  ) = getCatHelper,
  debugToggle,
): any {
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
  const prioritisedBreeds = Object.keys(config);

  // ...

  getCatHelper(prioritisedBreeds, catDefintions, debugToggle)
      .then(breed => setData(breed))
      .catch(() => false);

  // ...
}
```

My questions are:

1. How do I design this?
2. Should I care about the internals or just design the function and the function it returns?
3. When refactoring, should I be working from the outer or the inner function first?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What are your `catDefinitions`? Are they a global constant? A parameter to a function that you haven't shown?

Comment: Yes, `catDefinitions` are a parameter set for a function - react hook - and defaulting to a global constant. I have updated the issue with the code.

Comment: Is it `catDefinitions` or `audienceDefinitions`? And where in `useCatHook` are you calling the other two functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted the hook not to know about `CAT_DEFS` and to pass it straight to the `getCatHelper`.

I made this work:

```
export function getCatHelper {
    return (
        prioritisedBreeds,
        catDefintions,
        debugToggle,
        getDataLayer = getDataFromRequest
    ) {

    // ...

    };
}
```

```js
function useCatHook(
  config,
  getCat (
      prioritisedBreeds,
      catDefintions,
      debugToggle
  ) = getCatHelper(CAT_DEFS),
  debugToggle
) {

  // ...

}
```